# is range of wifi depends on both devices or only one

Tags: networking

Is the connection between wireless devices depends on both devices range or only one (the higher or lower)

for example i have a router with range 1km and a laptop with newtwork card 150m

Is the range of wifi connection (the range i can  connect to the router) depends on the range of router (1 km) or the laptop(150 m) ?

Comment: The Wi-Fi specification was designed to work to 100 meters to be the same as a wired UTP connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here on a Quora page](http://www.quora.com/Does-Wi-Fi-range-depend-only-on-router-without-phone-device), the answer of John Navas is summarised here :-

> Wi-Fi range is a function of the wireless router, the wireless client
>   device, the amount of radio interference from other sources, and the
>   amount of radio signal blockage by walls, floors, objects, etc.

So, YES, it does depend on both the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on both, as the communication is bidirectional. Since the range of of the adapter is only 150m, you cannot send radio waves any further and hence you cannot connect to the router any further(say 200 m), whatever its range is.